# SQL, how to treat structured infos

Tags: sql, unique, info

I need your help, I'm a little bit in trouble.

I have a "structured" info that has to be unique taken all field together, but can be not unique individually.

For example:

Columns: Two_Letters | Firts_Digit | Second_Digit | Third_Digit | Four_Letters

I want that the entry `AA|2|3|4|BBBB` is unique, but I can insert `AA|2|3|4|CCCC`.

Obviously letters can vary from A to Z and digit from 0 to 9.

Suggestion?

Comment: Don't store this values in DB as concatenated strings, but split it to separate columns. In this case you will be able to create unique key on these columns.

Comment: Add a unique constraint, `unique(Two_Letters, Firts_Digit, Second_Digit, Third_Digit, Four_Letters)`, to your table.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev they are not concatenated strings, and that is the problem. I have a code string structured that i choose to split in columns (that I've called "Field" in first post)

To JARLH: I've have unique-ified them via query and via mysql workbench gui, and if I insert (AA,1,2,3,AAAA) and (AA,1,3,4,BBBB) I have back error for "duplicate entry" on first column

Answer (score 0):

THINK SOLVED:
Since I've done all edits via MySQL Workbench, I do not consider differences between "checkbox UNIQUE" associated to each column and "unique constraint" that is really what I was looking for. So the solution for my problem is:
-ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (Two_Letters, Firts_Digit, Second_Digit, Third_Digit, Four_Letters);
associated with no checkbox checked for 'UQ' in gui editing table on MySQL WB.